# failed to run a simple SQL query for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I trying to run SQL query on a Pandas dataframe using pandasql.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql.sqldf as exec_sql

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b':[7, 8, 9]})
exec_sql("select top(3) * from df")
```

I'm having this error, that I could not find the reason.

```
error message:
PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "from": syntax error
[SQL: select top(3) * from df]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I try to read carefully the background of the error, from the
error's message [here](http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8) but I could not found the cause.
Maybe anyone might help to give me a track, please.

Comment: I would just use vanilla pandas: `df.head(3)`

Answer (score 1):

this is what you want

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql.sqldf as exec_sql

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b':[7, 8, 9]})
exec_sql("select * from df LIMIT 3;")
```

Limit 3 will give you the first 3 rows